# When I set the row Data of the Ag-Grid twice, I changed the cell value in that. But the second setting does not refresh the table

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I set the row data for the first time, then changed the value of the cell with node.setDataValue and api.refreshCells, but when I set the same row data as the first time, I found that the table was not refreshed, or I just modified it. The value of the cell.

Ag-Grid does not refresh because the rowData I provided twice is the same, and Node.setDataValue does not modify rowData. When I enter the internal comparison of agGridReact for the second time, I find that the two rowDatas have not changed, so there is no Refresh.

Comment: Hi Lawliet and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order for us to help you. Adding some of your relevant code would be a good start.

Comment: From your description, ag-grid functions as intended, i.e. if the data isn't changed (by your second update), then no refresh is done.

Comment: yes,So I have to refresh the form myself.